# Flask: return render_template stopping python script from continuously running

Tags: python, flask

I have the following code at the end of my Flask Script:

```
    while True:
        success, img = video.read()
        image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (15, 15), 0)

        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blur, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 14,
                                   param1=34, param2=10, minRadius=4, maxRadius=10)

        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

# Check if a new round has started
        if (len(circles[0, :]) == 7) and not is_round:
            start_time = time.time()  # Start time
            is_round = True
            curr_count = 0 
            round_total = 0 

        elif is_round:
            if len(circles[0, :]) == 1:
                end_time = time.time()   
                is_round = False
                time_taken = end_time - start_time
                print('Round time: ', str(
                    datetime.timedelta(seconds=time_taken))[2:7])

                times.append(time_taken)
                average = sum(times) / len(times)
                print('Average time: ', str(
                    datetime.timedelta(seconds=average))[2:7])

            elif len(circles[0, :]) < 7:
                curr_count = (7 - round_total) - len(circles[0, :])
                total += curr_count  
                round_total += curr_count  

            for i in circles[0, :]:
                # draw the outer circle
                cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

            Tracking()

        return render_template('theme1.html', output2=total)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The Tracking() does not repeat the script because it is blocked by render_template and app.run, how do i make it so the python script runs continuously? Thanks! EDIT: I have added more of the code, if anyone has a solution please tell me.

Comment: `app.run()` blocks throughout the time that the server is up and listening for requests. What are you trying to achieve by `Tracking()`? Can you share the code?

Comment: Hey! Tracking is the name of the function.... i thought that adding that line of code make it repeat the script, i edited the code and put tracking() before app.run, this works but now the output is being printed in the terminal instead of the webpage, do you know how to fix? Thanks

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to help you without seeing more of your code. Ideally provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have added more of the code, if you could help me i would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

HTTP views, i.e. `@app.route(...)`, are not designed for continuous data transmission like video streaming. That's what *websockets* are for.

Your program architecture needs to be changed so that:

1. The HTTP endpoint `"/"` will send a webpage that does not contain any image. Instead, it should contain a javascript code (in `<script>` tag) that will connect to a websocket from the browser, and display the video. [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcwnQW_AnC8) may help you.
2. In your python code you need to create a websocket endpoint (that will be called using `ws://...` instead of `http://...`). The endpoint should accept connections and start streaming images to them. In practice it would look like the `while` loop that you already have, but the data will be send to the socket.

Comment: The web server doesn't contain a video... it grabs data from the video and outputs it as an integer to the web server.. are you sure i have to do this? Before it was working fine but i added some code and now i cannot get it to output, i'll give it a go either way, thanks

Comment: I assumed you have a video source in your server (like a camera) and you want to process the image and display the image in a web page. Are my assumptions wrong? Can you clarify?

Comment: the video is not being displayed to the webpage, the video is used to track objects, i turn the track objects into integers (total). And i output the integers to the web server and it automatically refreshes the web page every 10 seconds to see if another object has appeared, the video is not displayed on the web server, just numbers

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll post another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the same code but you need to break it into 2 functions. One that continuously updates a shared variable with the number of object (and it should run in a separate thread to avoid blocking), and another one that returns the variable in a webpage.

The structure should look like this:

```py
from threading import Thread
...

app = Flask(__name__)
output_state = None


def output_updater_loop():
    nonlocal output_state  # important
    ...
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(1, 0)
    ...
    while True:
        success, img = video.read()
        ...
        output_state = ...


@app.route("/")
def get_page():
    return render_template(..., output_state=output_state)


output_updater_thread = Thread(
    name='output_updater_thread',
    target=output_updater_loop,
    daemon=True
)

output_updater_thread.start()  # Won't block

app.run(debug=True)
```

After you can do this, you can improve the code by using a mutex on output_state. Learn more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety

Comment: i have come across 2 problems:  1. no binding for nonlocal output_state (i fixed this by changing it to a global variable)   2. i have added my code but got the error from the line -  image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)